# ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown + unknown

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostGIS database and I have to compute new values for rows in a new column. These values should be the average of the values of several columns. So I do the query:

```
INSERT INTO bdps (da_m) 
VALUES (avg('da_1'+'da_2'+'da_3'+'da_4'+'da_5'+'da_6'+'da_7'));
```

In this query bdps is my database, da_m is the new column and da_1 to da_7 are existing columns that have double precision type.

da_m was created using

`ALTER TABLE bdps ADD COLUMN da_m double precision;`

I get the following error:

```
    ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown + unknown
LINE 2:  VALUES (avg('da_1'+'da_2'+'da_3'+'da_4'+'da_5'+'da_6'+'da_7...
                           ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown + unknown
SQL state: 42725
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 45
```

I google it and It has something to do with casts.
I run PostGreSQL 8.3 and the database is under PostGIS 1.5, on Windows 7.

Comment: You're trying to add varchars. Use double-quotes to refer to the column names, or leave them bare.

Comment: If I do this I get the error:

Comment: Sorry, If a do this i get the error: 'ERROR:  column "da_1" does not exist
LINE 2:  VALUES (avg(da_1+da_2+da_3+da_4+da_5+da_6+da_7));
                     ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "da_1" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 39
'

Comment: `ERROR:  column "da_1" does not exist
LINE 2:  VALUES (avg(da_1+da_2+da_3+da_4+da_5+da_6+da_7));
                     ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "da_1" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 39`

Comment: Please show us the **full** `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table `bdps`

Comment: The table comes from a shapefile loaded through PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader.

Comment: @user1165791: how does your comment explain the structure of the table? Without the table definition it's impossible to tell where your `column "da_1" does not exist` error comes from.

Answer (score 3):

You can produce an "inlined table" using VALUES and then apply your average to that:

```
update bdps
set da_m = (
    select avg(x)
    from (values (da_1), (da_2), (da_3), (da_4), (da_5), (da_6), (da_7)) as dt(x)
)
```

that saves you from messing around with COALESCE, SIGN, counting columns by hand, etc.

And as [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) (but with SQL and PostgreSQL skills) mentioned:

- Don't use single quotes with column names, table names, or other identifiers. Use double quotes if you need to worry about upper/lower case issues or strange characters (or better, rename your columns and save some grief).
- Use UPDATE to update existing rows, INSERT for is adding new rows.